# Adding a header to a PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

So I have found that android PreferenceScreen is not very style-friendly.  Is there a semi-simple way to just add a header (say an image) to the preferencescreen before the preferences are shown?  I am currently extending the PreferenceActivity class, but could someone show me how to add a linear layout to the header?

Thanks

Comment: "So I have found that android PreferenceScreen is not very style-friendly" -- that is because you should be leaving them alone. The whole *point* of `PreferenceScreen` is for them to look the same from app to app. Google does not enforce human interface guidelines the way Apple does; however, savvy developers will still aim for consistency with other apps and the OS where possible. Users, in blog comments and discussion boards, ridicule Android developers who do otherwise, and as such developers give Android a bad name. Leave the `PreferenceScreen` styling alone, please.

Comment: Yes yes, I know.  Honestly I do no want to touch the PreferenceScreen, but that doesn't stop a client from demanding it.

Comment: Then point them to this StackOverflow comment. To the client: you are not more important than your users, and you are not more important than the platform.

Comment: CommonsWare makes a good point. Android, unlike the iPhone, targets different devices. Using the default means that your app will work across those devices, customizing a preference screen like your client is requesting could result in problems on specific devices. Does your client understand this?

Comment: Yes they do, however the client is a huge corporation with their own set of ideas of what is 'right' and 'wrong'.  The solution was to make a ton of activities with listviews that mimic preference activities.  Basically I had to write my own listviews, listview items, list view adapters, on-click dialogs, and code to save and retrieve the sharedpreferences manually.  Ya gotta do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In my app I do exactly what you are requesting like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    setContentView(R.layout.preferences_layout);
}
```

and in the `preferences_layout.xml` file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myCustomImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/xmas"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
/>
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myCustomImageView"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice the `android:id` set on the `ListView` in the xml
Now you have control over the layout of the preferences screen and use the default style for the preferences as long as you use built-in preferences.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed from your comments that you already fixed it the hard way. Well...maybe someone else is looking for a solution

Comment: yep, someone else did :) and this solution works great, thanks!

Comment: This will crash on ICS devices and tablets!

Comment: @Profete162 It doesn't crash on ICS.

Comment: I used this on my Nexus 7 and it got crash with the error: `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

Comment: Note that PreferenceActivity derives from ListActivity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation with Mircea approach: you can't remove the title at the top:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    ...
```

This results in "`requestfeature()` must be called before adding content".

Comment: Couldn't you make the `requestWindowFeature` call before calling `super.onCreate`?