# Add ads header in new honeycomb PreferenceActivity with headers

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to add an ads banner on the top or bottom of a new Honeycomb PreferenceActivity with headers. 
I tried the solution commented on [Adding a header to a PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443491/adding-a-header-to-a-PreferenceActivity) but it doesn't work for new activities. 
Any easy way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the sample code [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) as an example of how to add headers to the PreferenceActivity?

Comment: With headers you add a preference section on the right lateral list. But I want to add a top header occupying all the space.